# Pycharm Intellisense no working on new class

Tags: python, pycharm, code-completion

In Pycharm, I create a new python class with properties:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, _name):
        self._name = _name
```

When I try to use this class in another file I import it like this:

```
from filename import Item
```

Then I try to use intellisense when I type something like this:

```
item = Item()
print(item.<ALT Enter>
```

I never get intellisense option for property name until it appears at least once in the file

Is there anything I'm doing to the class definition that's muting the intellisense? Is there anything I can do help it?

Comment: Sorry to say it, but I just gave it a try and it worked fine. If you put print(item.name) and run it, does it run ok?

Comment: It runs fine yes, this is in a context of many, many other modules and classes in one project. My main question is really, am I doing anything bad in terms of file/class spec, bc if you don't do a class and just include a file with  top level def the intellisense works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a method called **get** implemented. After removing (changing the name) everything worked fine.

Comment: If you can give a proper example, explaining what you exactly did, please edit the answer and do so.